# TypeError: store.getState is not a function. (In 'store.getState()', 'store.getState' is undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hi guys i was setting up redux in my react native project but facing some issues while setup even though i am pretty sure i haven't used getState till now but as ssons as app runs i get error

> TypeError: store.getState is not a function. (In 'store.getState()',
> 'store.getState' is undefined)

my code is as

reducers / hireducer.js

```
import { HI } from "../constants";
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
};
const countReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HI:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default countReducer;
```

reducers / index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import hiReducer from "./hireducer.js";
export default combineReducers({
  hi: hiReducer,
});
```

store / configStore

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "../reducers/index";

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(reducers);
};
export default configureStore;
```

App.js

```
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AuthNavigator from "./navigations/AuthNavigation";
import { withHOC } from "./index.js";
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default withHOC(App);
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configStore from "./redux/store/configStore";
export const withHOC = (App) => (props) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={configStore}>
      <App {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

even though if i normally wrap in  without providing store i still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your `configStore` returns a function instead of a store object.

So you rather call the function in your app like

```
<Provider store={configStore()}>
  <App {...props} />
</Provider>
```

Or you create a store object from configStore like

```
const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(reducers);
};
export default configureStore();
```